# Need to include a DocumentFormat.OpenXML dll in project

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization project where I'm importing an Excel file content into the Lot/Ser No. Allocation grid.  This works fine on my machine, but I had to download the DocumentFormat.OpenXml dll and include a reference in my class library project in order to do this.  I've created a customization project, but when someone else tries to use it, that reference and that file are not there.  I've tried to include it in the files section of the customization manager, but I have no way of doing that (can't browse to a file) - not that that would make any difference anyway, since that's the bin folder of the website, and not the class library.

Bottom line:  Is there a way to include a dll file that's used in the class library project references in a customization package?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add the dll file in Bin folder of your local website -> the file should appear in the Add Files dialog inside Customization Project Manager
2. Select the dll file in the Add Files dialog and click Save

After that, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll becomes a part of your customization package, which will always deploy it together with your extension library

Answer (score 1):

Ruslan provided a good answer explaining how to include your custom DLL, however you might want to know that there are built in functions to read Excel files which make inclusion of third-party libraries unnecessary. Please refer to the following article: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2016/03/reading-excel-file-acumatica.html?m=1

Comment: Thanks Gabriel - that's awesome!